# Update Query in GRN

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a stock management system and I have a problem with updating part in good received note. When we purchase goods, we get a good received note, so when we get the items the number of items has to be updated (has to be added to the remaining goods) according to the item code. 
According to the following code data from GRN will be extracted and will be saved in GRN1 and GRN2 tables. There's another table called Item_Supplier, when we receive goods Stock in hand field in Item_Supplier table has to updated according to the item_Id as well.

Problem is following code does not work.

```
Connection ss = Class_DB.myconnection();
                    Statement st = ss.createStatement();
```

-

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select stock_in_hand from item_supplier where item_ID =('" + TF_GRN_ITEMID.getText() + "')");

grniid = TF_GRN_NO_OF_ITEM.getText();

while (rs.next()) {
    nit = rs.getString("stock_in_hand");    
}

sumn = grniid + nit;

st.executeUpdate("insert into grn1 values('" + TF_GRN_GRNNO.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_SUPPLIERID.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_AMOUNT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_DATE.getText() + "')");
st.executeUpdate("insert into grn2 values('" + TF_GRN_GRNNO.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_ITEMID.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_EXP_DATE.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_TAX.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_NO_OF_ITEM.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_GAMOUNT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_NAMOUNT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_QTY.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_UNIT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_FREE.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_DIS.getText() + "')");
st.executeUpdate("update item_supplier set stock_in_hand='" + sumn + "' where item_ID='" + TF_GRN_ITEMID.getText() + "'");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
```

Please help.

Comment: What is `Class_DB`? What is `GRN`?

Comment: class_DB is a connection class used to connect the database. these are the codes in the class.                                                                      public class Class_DB {
    public static Connection myconnection()throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection cd=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/v7database", "root", "123");
    return cd;
    }
}

Comment: GRN stands for Good Received Note.When we receive items we get a GRN from the supplier. It is hard copy, where all the details about the items, date, qty, no of items etc..... are mentioned.